# Пропажа крестика в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Всем привет. Опытные пользователи Android Studio подскажите пожалуйста как вернуть здесь кнопку закрытия вкладок. Не могу понять как их вернуть и когда они пропали. Спасибо всем кро поможет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (или Файл - Settings), Editor - General - Editor Tabs, выбрать Right или Left:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо человечище